# Cannot get content from angular editor correctly

Tags: angular

I have a problem like this. I am making an angular application. In there I have put angular editor.

This is my particular component.html where I have embedded angular editor.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body class="fixed-nav sticky-footer bg-dark" id="page-top">
<!-- Navigation-->
<app-adminnavbar></app-adminnavbar>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <form (submit)="putNews()">
      <app-ngx-editor [placeholder]="'Enter text here...'" [spellcheck]="true" name="htmlContent" [(ngModel)]="htmlContent" minHeight="50px" Width="50px" ></app-ngx-editor>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Post News</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <app-adminfooter></app-adminfooter>

  <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
  </a>

</div>
</body>
```

This is my particular component.ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BootstrapAlertService, BootstrapAlert } from 'ngx-bootstrap-alert';
import { NewsService} from '../../shared/news.service';
import {News} from "../../shared/news";



@Component({
  selector: 'app-news',
  templateUrl: './news.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news.component.css'],
  providers: [NewsService]
})
export class NewsComponent implements OnInit {

  public news:News = new News();
  htmlContent: any;
  constructor(private newsService: NewsService,private bootstrapAlertService:BootstrapAlertService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  putNews(){
    this.news.content=this.htmlContent;
    this.newsService.putNews(this.news).subscribe((res)=>{
      this.bootstrapAlertService.alert(new BootstrapAlert("Succesfully Post a news!", "alert-success"));
    });
  }

}
```

When I send that to the database it sending with div tags and all HTML element.
Can Somone help me to remove those HTML tags and only the data to the database?

Thank You!!!

Comment: If you remove all the HTML tags, you will lose any formatting. In that case, why use ngx-editor if you're only interested in the text? You could just use a text-area

Comment: Then can you tell me a way to show that data without showing those tags? It means when I retrieve data it shows the data with those tags.

Comment: How do you want to show it? Just in a div or something? If so, just use `<div [innerHTML]="htmlContent"></div>`

Comment: Thank You. It works